# progress command doesn't show mv progress

Tags: mv, coreutils, progress-information

I installed `progress` by `brew install progress`

```
% progress -v
progress version 0.13
```

And while I'm using `mv` command I used `progress -w`, but it failed with wrong permission error.

```
progress -w
No command currently running: cp, mv, dd, tar, cat, rsync, grep, fgrep, egrep, cut, sort, md5sum, sha1sum, sha224sum, sha256sum, sha384sum, sha512sum, adb, gzip, gunzip, bzip2, bunzip2, xz, unxz, lzma, unlzma, zcat, bzcat, lzcat, or wrong permissions.
```

Should I change permission somewhere to use `progress`?
What am I doing wrong?

I'm using macOS Sierra version `10.12.6`.

#### More Info

I executed `progress -w` just after `mv` command that moved about 30GB data from internal SSD to external HDD. And I checked after the error message of `progress`, the `mv` command was still working.

```
% which mv
/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin/mv
% mv --version
mv (GNU coreutils) 8.27
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Mike Parker, David MacKenzie, and Jim Meyering.
```

Comment: Regardless of what which says: isn't mv a shell builtin command?

Answer (score 1):

Coreutil commands run with sudo require `progress` to be run with sudo in order to view the current progress.

In other words, if you ran cp, mv, etc as sudo, you need to run `sudo progress`.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is working fine

```
progress -w
No command currently running: cp, mv, dd, tar, cat, rsync, grep, fgrep, egrep, cut, sort, md5sum, sha1sum, sha224sum, sha256sum, sha384sum, sha512sum, adb, gzip, gunzip, bzip2, bunzip2, xz, unxz, lzma, unlzma, zcat, bzcat, lzcat, or wrong permissions.
```

means there is no mv,cp process currently running

maybe the file is moved before you run progress -w

Comment: I'm pretty sure, the `mv` command was still active. I'll add details to my question.